# FileUriExposedException в Android 7

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Делаю снимок в дефолтной камере (Intent), когда тестирую на Android 7.0, то получаю ошибку:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pic.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

в этом методе:

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pic.jpg"):

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
        Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Что где нужно поменять, что бы этот метод отрабатывал без ошибок?

Answer (score 0):

Может надо Uri в Intent засунуть?

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
```

Comment: Не, это есть в коде, случайно удалила эту строчку когда постила вопрос, только что обновила

Comment: может быть этот ответ поможет - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Это похоже оно, сейчас буду пробовать